# Spark (Scala) update DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I create the dataframe with schema in the following way:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(
Seq(
  Row("first", 2.0),
  Row("test", 1.5),
  Row("choose", 8.0)
 )
)

val schema: StructType = new StructType()
.add(StructField("id", StringType, true))
.add(StructField("val1", DoubleType, true))

val dfWithSchema = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

And I want to update id-column with arbitrary value:

I tried this:

```
 dfWithSchema.withColumn("id", col("id").+(Random.nextString(10)))
```

But without expected result.
Is there any way to do this by Spark 2.13 - ?

Comment: You CAN NOT update a dataframe. You can create another dataframe with added, removed or modified columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate with spark using the concat function:

```
dfWithSchema.withColumn("id", concat(col("id"),lit(Random.nextString(10)))).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the following solution:

```
dfWithSchema.withColumn("id", when(col("id").isNotNull, Random.nextString(10)))
```

However I am surprised that there are no direct way to update dataframe with new column values, but only by condition of the existing column values.